# How do I SqlQuery this data with SQL?

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

My table data looks like this:

```
 LogId  EmployeeId      LogTime                      Date
    31          22  09:59:00 AM   2011-11-04 00:00:00.000
    40          22  12:15:00 PM   2011-11-04 00:00:00.000
    43          22  13:15:00 PM   2011-11-04 00:00:00.000 
    45          22  18:16:00 PM   2011-11-04 00:00:00.000
    47          22  18:40:00 PM   2011-11-04 00:00:00.000
```

I want this type of data in my report:

```
SNo.  EmpID  In Duration  Out Duration  Punch Records       
1     22   09:59       18:16            (09:59 in, 12:15 out, 13:15 in, 18:16 out)
```

-------Answered Query----------

```
if object_id('tempdb..#timing') is not null drop table #timing

create table #timing (
    logid int identity(1, 1),
    empid int,
    logtime datetime
)

insert into #timing
select 11, '20111201 8:03' union all select 11, '20111201 8:09' union all
select 12, '20111201 8:38' union all select 12, '20111201 9:31' union all
select 12, '20111201 9:31' union all select 12, '20111201 9:36' union all
select 11, '20111201 9:37' union all select 11, '20111201 9:44' union all
select 11, '20111201 9:48' union all select 11, '20111201 9:50'


;with cte as (
    select top 100 percent 
        empid,
        cast(datepart(hh, logtime) as varchar(2)) + ':' +
        right('0' + cast(datepart(mi, logtime) as varchar(2)), 2) as logtime,
        row_number() over (partition by empid order by logid) as row
    from #timing
    order by logid asc
)
select c1.empid as EmployeeID, min(c1.logtime) as InTime, max(c2.logtime) as OutTime, min(isnull(p.punches, '')) as Punches
from cte c1
join cte c2 on c1.row + 1 = c2.row and c1.empid = c2.empid
left join (
    select empid,
        (select '(' + stuff(
            (select ', ' +c1.logtime + ' In, ' + c2.logtime + ' Out'
            from cte c1
            join cte c2 on c1.row + 1 = c2.row and c1.empid = c2.empid
            where c1.row % 2 = 1 and c3.empid = c1.empid
            for xml path(''), type).value('text()[1]','varchar(max)'), 1, 2, '') + ')'
        ) as punches
    from cte c3
    group by empid
) as p on p.empid = c1.empid
group by c1.empid
order by c1.empid
```

In this query i have used Logtime field type varchar as a string and Date field as a DateTime so help me for changes in this query.

this query is perfect but i have used logtime as varchar type.so i dont get perfect output in my report.

how can achieve it ?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could update your question with something that shows what the problem is. The output as it is now and what you want it to be.

Comment: see my edit..@Mikael Eriksson

Comment: The only difference that I can see between what you already have and what you want is the extra `0` in the hour part of the time when the time is less than `10:00`. Is that what you need fixing?

Comment: In this given query logtime  field type is Datetime but i want this logtime field as varchar(as a string) in this query..how can i change datetime to varchar in this query ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "`logtime` is a datetime in the query". `logtime` is a column in table `#timing` that is datetime. `logtime`is also a derived **varchar** column in the CTE. All fields except `EmployeeID` is varchar in the result set from the query.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are are looking for:

```
convert(min(c1.logtime), varchar(12), 14) as InTime
```

?

More on datatype conversion in SQLServer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).